# Using PHP variables in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables

I am trying to use PHP variables in an INSERT SQL statement. Ive seen previous answers to this but can not get mine to work. Here is the code..

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (message_id, from, content) values ('', " . $uid . ", 'test message content')");
```

Comment: You **really** don't want to do this. Look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parameterized+sql instead.

Comment: I'd read up on SQL injection attacks and how to prevent them. This can work - but you need to make sure you are defending against these things as they are very easy to do for an attacker - and what Nate said - parameterized queries

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main problem is that `from` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html) and should be in backticks.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (message_id, `from`, content) VALUES ...");
```

But I'd also advise you to stop using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. I'd recommend that you take a look at PDO and prepared statements with parameters.

Comment: Ahhh.. silly me. Cant believe i did not notice the FROM word myself. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If message_id is primary key, you don't need to include it in the query unless you have a value..

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (`from`, `content`) values (" . $uid . ", 'test message content')");
```

Comment: message_id, even if it's the PK, isn't necessarily an autoincrement!

Comment: re: auto-increment, with mysql4 an empty string was (incorrectly) permissable. The advent of PHP5 caused this behaviour to stop, so you should either do as J A says or use an integer 0 (unquoted), if it is indeed an auto-increment of course.  Caught me out when I upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three issues in your query. Two of them are syntax errors and one is a huge vulnerability.

To make the query work, you should write it as follows:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (message_id, `from`, content) values ('', '" . $uid . "', 'test message content')");`
```

Here's a summary of the errors:
 - As another user indicated, "from" is a keyword and you should not use it to name table columns. If you really want to use such name, you must use backticks to indicate it in the query.
 - The value of $uid should be enclosed by single quotes.
 - The third, and most important error, is that your query is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use prepared statements, which would protect you from such attacks.